# Searching via Tags in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to search on Tags within SharePoint 2010? I know you can refine your search based on Tag (Search for a keyword, then filter by Tags) and you can use the "Tag Cloud", but that doesnt let you search by more then one Tag. How would I for instance, search  for some documents that I have tagged as "Technical" and "Internal", and return all items tagged with both of those tags?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at our product MatchPoint for SharePoint ([www.colygon.com](http://www.colygon.com)). It provides the possibility to search for documents on tags with refinement and many other cool stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Bender, Is there nothing out of the box that deals with searching for Tags then?